# Android 4.3 keychain example

Tags: android, keychain, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am trying to understand the keychain concept in android 4.3 and I will really appreciate it if I can get a example to understand it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was reading about it right now.

Basically the KeyChain class provides access to private keys and their corresponding certificate chains in credential storage. (Google says)

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) is Google's reference.

Also you can check [this](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/using-ics-keychain-api.html) link.

[Here](http://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/tree/master/KeyChainDemo) you have a code sample too.

I hope it helps to you ;)

Comment: Sample Code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/KeyChainDemo/src/com/example/android/keychain/KeyChainDemoActivity.java